# Using Prototype with "Namespace" for existing object

Tags: javascript, namespaces, prototype

I am looking to achieve something along the following.

```
HTMLSpanElement.prototype.testNS = {
  _this: this,
  testFunc: function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML)  //undefined as expected as this is the testFunc object
  },
  testFunc2: function() {
    console.log(this._this) //Window object
  }
}
```

My goal is to add some helper functions directly to a span element in this case.

So, if I had the following:

```
<span>test</span>
```

I could find the span and call this code to return "test"

```
spanElement.testNS.testFunc()
```

I know that a function retains scope of it's parent when I do it like so...

```
HTMLSpanElement.prototype.testFunc = function() {
   console.log(this.innerHTML)
}
```

But I am attempting to organize the code a bit and make it more obvious where the functions are coming from when I add them, and I can't seem to find a way to retain scope, when I do a normal JSON object grab the this scope into `_this: this` it just returns the global scope of "window".

Comment: *"as this is the testFunc object"* `this` will never refer to the function object itself. It refers to `panElement.testNS` if you call the function as `spanElement.testNS.testFunc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** You shouldn't be trying to modify the prototypes on built-in types, especially host objects. It's a bad idea.

---

The reason your approach isn't working for you is that the functions are being called with the `testNS` object as the `this`.

You can get this to work if you define `testNS` as a property with a getter function, using `Object.defineProperty`. The reason this works is that the `get` function runs in the context of the object on which the property is being accessed (which would be the span):

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLSpanElement.prototype, 'testNS', { 
  get: function() {
    var _this = this;
    return {
      testFunc: function() {
        console.log(_this.innerHTML)
      },
      testFunc2: function() {
        console.log(_this)
      }
    }
  }
});
var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');

span.testNS.testFunc();
span.testNS.testFunc2();
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">Wah-hoo!</span>
```

A more "vanilla" approach is to just have `testNS` be a plain function and call it like one. This works because `testNS` is called in the context of the object on which it is being called (again, the span):

```js
HTMLSpanElement.prototype.testNS = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return {
    testFunc: function() {
      console.log(_this.innerHTML)
    },
    testFunc2: function() {
      console.log(_this)
    }
  }
}

var span = document.getElementById('mySpan');

span.testNS().testFunc();
span.testNS().testFunc2();
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">Wah-hoo!</span>
```

Comment: Hey can we do this using Object.create()

Comment: @AnkitPandey I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Actually I am trying like HTMLSpanElement.prototype.testNS = Object.create()    in create I want to put {testFunc: function()...}

Comment: I agree, I don't think I should be doing built-in types, it was just easier to use an example of a built-in type instead of pasting a huge amount of code. I will take a look at these examples I knew I could do the dual functions, I was just trying to learn how to keep the scope.

Comment: @AnkitPandey I can't think of a way to make that work here.

Comment: Any plunker url please.

Comment: @AnkitPandey A plunker URL for what? I said I don't know of a way to get anything like OP's request to work involving Object.create(). I can't even think of a way that it would help.

Answer (score 1):

When you call a function as `foo.bar()` then `this` inside `bar` refers to `foo`. Hence if you call the function as `spanElement.testNS.testFunc()`, `this` refers to `spanElement.testNS`.

`_this: this,` cannot work because `this` cannot refer to a `<span>` element.

To get access to `spanElement` from `testFunc` you could implement `testNS` as a **getter**:

```js
Object.defineProperty(HTMLSpanElement.prototype, 'testNS', {
  get: function() {
    var element = this;
    return {
      testFunc: function() {
        console.log(element.innerHTML);
      },
    };
  },
});

document.querySelector('span').testNS.testFunc();
```

```html
<span>foo</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a strange requirement I wrote a an equivalent strange solution :-)
Basically the createElement has been overriden in order to add a namespace object literal and then define a new function testFunc on top of the namespace using the instance of the element binded to the function

```
!function(){
    var defaultNamespace = "testNS";
    var createElement = document.createElement;

    document.createElement = function(tag, namespace) {
        var element = createElement.apply(document, arguments);

        element[namespace || defaultNamespace] = {
            testFunc : function() {
                console.log(this.innerHTML);
            }.bind(element)
        };

        return element; 
    }    
}();

var span = document.createElement("span");
```

Comment: It is a bit strange, I was more curious than anything, I am attempting to learn more about scoping in javascript and I was playing around with it a bit.